# variable.Property = "test" vs Object.defineProperty(variable,"Property")

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

If I want to give a variable `a` a property `P` (non-accessor property) *and* I do not care if it's configurable/enumerable/writable.

I can be 100% sure it is in fact more beneficial (in all ways you can think of) to simply do a

```
a.P=value     // or
a["P"]=value
```

instead of using

```
Object.defineProperty
```

So basically as a rule, we should not touch that [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) unless we need to create accessors and/or we want to control the configurable/writable/enumerable status of the properties?

Comment: this article may helps u : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/scriptjunkie/gg602402.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's "more beneficial", but these are identical in functionality:

```
a.p = value;

Object.defineProperty(a, 'p', {
    enumerable   : true,
    writable     : true,
    configurable : true,
    value        : value
});
```

Obviously the latter is much more verbose, also ***much*** slower (roughly 1,000x slower in Chrome) if you're defining many properties:

http://jsperf.com/setting-object-properties

Comment: not only that, I'm actually pretty sure its slower (even if its negligible)

Comment: besides all browsers / major browsers are supporting that first form currently, and will support that first form for at least another 20 years

Comment: Well I'm assuming that the OP knows about browser-compatibility with Object.defineProperty, or at least I'm hoping :)  ... And really?  It was worth editing your comment from "15" to "20" years? :P

Comment: i don't understand ur question

Comment: @Pacerier - Hehe, yeah it's MUCH slower (944x slower in Chrome)

Comment: @cwolves assuming I'd use this *syntax* pretty often, that is pretty detrimental

Comment: @Pacerier - Yeah, me too.  I didn't think it would be nearly 1,000 times slower.