# Difference between defining and assigning property

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between assigning a property to an object and defining it?Which one is better and how?

**This**

```
 Object.defineProperty(obj,p,propDesc)
```

**Or simply**

```
 obj.p="someValue";
```

Comment: A *propertyDesciptor* is not the `something` *value*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Definition versus assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989483/definition-versus-assignment)

Answer (score 2):

[`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) lets you set a whole bunch of options about that property.  Like `enumerable` and `writable`.

When you do `obj.p = 'something';`, you're setting a property with the "default" options.

Neither is "better", they each have their own uses.  Which one you use depends on your requirements.

Comment: Property assignment is frequently used to add new properties to an object. My post explained that that can cause problems. Hence, it is best to follow the simple rules:

If you want to create a new property, use definition.

If you want to change the value of a property, use assignment.

Comment: @Maizere: Nope. These cases in which it causes problems do not exist in normal code, and you should use assignment everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

As found on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

"
This method allows precise addition to or modification of a property on an object. Normal property addition through assignment creates properties which show up during property enumeration (for...in loop or Object.keys method), whose values may be changed, and which may be deleted. This method allows these extra details to be changed from their defaults."